# What does a dot after the file permission bits mean?

Tags: linux, permissions, ls

I performed an `ls -la` on directory on my CentOS 6.4 server here and the permissions for a given file came out as:

```
-rwxr-xr-x.
```

I understand what `-rwxr-xr-x` means, what I don't understand is the `.` after the last attribute.

Can someone explain it to me? Is it harmful in any way? Can it be removed?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> GNU `ls` uses a `.` character to indicate a file with an SELinux
>    security context, but no other alternate access method.

-- From `ls` man page ([`info coreutils 'ls invocation'`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html)).

Comment: the file in question is the service definition for the tomcat server. So I should be fine, right?

Comment: I guess so. You can read this for more info: https://www.owasp.org/images/0/01/Secure_Web_App_Server_McRee_OWASP.pdf

Comment: Does it means that the `selinux` is on.

Answer (score 3):

To see the actual security context applied to the file run this:

```
ls -Z
```

The security contexts can be assigned to a file even having SELinux disabled. You can check your security context with this:

```
id -Z
```

If SELinux is disabled you will get this  message:

```
id: --context (-Z) works only on an SELinux-enabled kernel
```