# Chown permission denied on owned dir

Tags: bash, rhel, chown

I have following directory (`/usr/local`)

```
rwxr-xr-x. 43 root root  4096 Jul 25 14:19 .
rwxr-xr-x. 14 root root  4096 Feb 21 10:27 ..
rwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Jun 28  2011 bin
[...]
rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  8192 Jul 25 13:41 bad_dir
rwxr-xr-x.  4 root root  4096 Mar 28 11:56 good_dir
```

I am logged as root. When I run `chown root:root good_dir` everything is ok, but when I run `chown root:root bad_dir` I got `chown: changing ownership of '/usr/local/bad_dir': Permission denied`

What is wrong with bad_dir? What should I change to make `chown` working correctly?
I see a dot in the end of permissions, but I don't know what does it mean.

**Update**

Running

```
echo 0 > /selinux/enforce
chmod 755 bad_dir
```

gives also `chmod: changing permissions of 'bad_dir': Permission denied`

**Update 2**

Output of `ls -la /usr` is

```
total 128
drwxr-xr-x.  14 root root  4096 Feb 21 10:27 .
dr-xr-xr-x.  24 root root  4096 May 28 08:22 ..
dr-xr-xr-x.   2 root root 28672 Jun 27 10:29 bin
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 Jun 28  2011 etc
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 Jun 28  2011 games
drwxr-xr-x.  36 root root  4096 Jul 23 14:04 include
dr-xr-xr-x.  12 root root  4096 Apr 11 17:10 lib
dr-xr-xr-x.  45 root root 36864 Jul 23 14:04 lib64
drwxr-xr-x.  14 root root  4096 Mar 28 11:58 libexec
drwxr-xr-x.  43 root root  4096 Jul 25 14:34 local
drwxr-xr-x.   3 root root  4096 Feb 21 10:27 man
dr-xr-xr-x.   2 root root 12288 Jul 23 14:04 sbin
drwxr-xr-x. 106 root root  4096 Mar 28 12:00 share
drwxr-xr-x.   4 root root  4096 Nov 20  2013 src
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    10 Nov 20  2013 tmp -> ../var/tmp
```

Comment: See [What does a dot after the file permission bits mean?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102624/what-does-a-dot-after-the-file-permission-bits-mean)

Comment: @Garath, what is the output of `ls -la /usr`?

Comment: @Ramesh Added to question

Comment: @Garath, thanks. Also, could you please tell the output of `ls -la /usr/local`?

Comment: @Ramesh it is in the top of the question (the first one)

Comment: Please include the output of `lsattr /-d usr/local/bad_dir`

Comment: @CristianCiupitu I got: `lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags`

Comment: Is this on an NFS mount or anything like that?

Comment: @JoelDavis no it isn't

Comment: `stat --format='%D' /usr/local /usr/local/bad_dir`

Comment: shorter version of the above would be `df -hP /usr/local/bad_dir`

Answer (score 6):

The directories need x permission to open. You can probably do,

`chmod 755 bad_dir` and then try your `chown` command.

According to [here](https://superuser.com/a/230561/252686), the dot at end means,

According to [`ls.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c?id=v8.21#n3785) (line 3785), `.` means an [SELinux ACL](https://superuser.com/a/230561/252686). (`+` means a [general ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list#Filesystem_ACLs).)

If it is SELinux messing, use [setenforce](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setenforce.8.html) to modify its mode. Run `setenforce 0` to put SELinux in permissive mode and `setenforce 1` to put it back into enforcing mode.

Comment: When I run `chmod 755 bad_dir` I got `chmod: changing permissions of 'bad_dir': Permission denied`

Comment: @Garath, you should disable your selinux temporarily and then try. See my updated answer.

Comment: I doesnt' work. See my update

Comment: @Garath: What's the output of command `getenforce`? Please run `setenforce 0` and not `echo 0 > /selinux/enforce`.

Comment: Could you do a `getfacl bad_dir` ? Maybe it's just an ACL to fix :)

Answer (score 3):

I made a stupid mistake. We had few machines provisioned identically, but one (with this problem) was changed by one of my colleagues.

The `bad_dir` was mounted NFS, which explains all problems. Thanks to Joel Davis which suggest me to check this again I solved my issue.