# What enable `mysql` user to write a file into /var/log?

Tags: var

`/var/log/` belongs to root user:

```
$ ls -ld /var/log
drwxr-xr-x. 13 root root 4096 Mar 31 19:23 /var/log
```

As you can see the `other` do not have the write privilege and there's no sticky bit (as for the `/tmp/` folder).

But if I look into this folder the mysql user is able to write a file into it:

```
$ ls -l /var/log |grep mysql
drwxr-x---  2 mysql  mysql     4096 Mar 30 16:03 mysql
```

How is the mysql user able to create files into this directory? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`d` in `drwxr-x---` indicates the `mysql` file is of the type directory. The directory was most likely created by `root`, its ownership and permissions adjusted. This was a one-time job during the installation of MySQL or whatever.

Additionally `.` in `drwxr-xr-x.` for `/var/log` [indicates there's an SELinux security context](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102625/108618). I know little about SELinux but I believe one can grant additional permissions with it. If you think the `mysql` directory was created not exactly by `root` then investigate this lead.

The `mysql` user can create files *inside* the `mysql` directory. For this the lack of write permission in `/var/log` is irrelevant.

You may be more familiar with this fact:
In Linux regular users cannot create files directly in `/home`. Yet each one has got their own directory inside `/home` where they can create files (`/home/yves`, `/home/kamil`, `/home/bob`).

Similarly `mysql` has got a directory inside `/var/log` to create log files there.