# 'which' behaves inconsistently on different machines - Why the difference?

Tags: linux, which, multiple-machines

My company has multiple servers that were setup to be identical. After using dev32 for several weeks, `which` stopped functioning. I go to dev35 and get similar behavior -- works for several weeks then one day it stops. dev36 is ok for now, but following this pattern I'll eventually run out of systems to use.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this behavior?

```
dev32 ~> which python3
python3: Command not found.
dev35 ~> which python3
python3: Command not found.
dev36 ~> which python3
/bin/python3

dev32 ~> ls -al /bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     9 Jan 17 10:18 /bin/python3 -> python3.6
-rwxr-x---. 2 root root 11328 Nov 16  2020 /bin/python3.6
-rwxr-x---. 2 root root 11328 Nov 16  2020 /bin/python3.6m
dev32 ~> echo $PATH
.:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/bsd:/usr/sbin:/home/<username>/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/etc:/usr/local/sbin:/etc:/usr/etc:/usr/gnu/bin

dev35 ~> ls -al /bin/python3*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     9 Jan 17 10:11 /bin/python3 -> python3.6
-rwxr-x---. 2 root root 11328 Nov 16  2020 /bin/python3.6
-rwxr-x---. 2 root root 11328 Nov 16  2020 /bin/python3.6m
dev35 ~> echo $PATH
.:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/bsd:/usr/sbin:/home/<username>/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/etc:/usr/local/sbin:/etc:/usr/etc:/usr/gnu/bin

dev36 ~> ls -al /bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     9 Jan 17 10:18 /bin/python3 -> python3.6
-rwxr-x---. 3 root root 11328 Nov 16  2020 /bin/python3.6
-rwxr-x---. 2 root root 11328 Nov 16  2020 /bin/python3.6m
dev36 ~> echo $PATH
.:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/bsd:/usr/sbin:/home/<username>/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/etc:/usr/local/sbin:/etc:/usr/etc:/usr/gnu/bin
```

Even after `cd /bin`, `which` cannot find python3

Other knowns:

- All servers are CentOS 7.9, uname -a matches
- Ran `rpm -qa | sort > $HOSTNAME.txt` on each server and compared. results are identical
- bash v4.2.26, tcsh v6.18.01 (same across all systems)
- Behavior confirmed by multiple users; tcsh & bash yield same results. One user's shell uses system defaults (no ~/.bashrc, ~/.tcshrc or ~/.login), I customize mine.
- IT says they haven't changed anything beyond standard monthly patching that is applied consistently to all servers.
- Problem persists across reboots

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: What does your `ls` report on the two failing systems?

Comment: On dev32 `ls /bin` and `echo "$PATH"`. Also take a look in the package manager's log.

Comment: Having `.` as the first element in `$PATH` is a potential security issue. It's better not to include it at all, but if you must then put it at the end of the list

Comment: stupid question, does simply running `python3 --version` still work on all three machines?

Comment: The `.` at the end of the mode string from `ls` suggests there is an SELinux context - I wonder if that is a factor? See for example [What does a dot after the file permission bits mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102624/what-does-a-dot-after-the-file-permission-bits-mean)

Comment: Is it just the `which` command that's misbehaving (in which case an obvious workaround is to [stop using it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)), or do saner commands (`type`, `command -v`, …) also not find exeutables?

Comment: @roima & @tomasz - Added requested info to description

@roima - Thanks for the tip on the '.' in my $PATH. I'll fix that.

Marcus Muller - Running `python3 --version` on all 3x systems returns '3.6.8'

@steeldriver - I'll read up on that next

Comment: Gilles - The part that gets me is using 'which' used to work, but recently stopped working, and only on a couple of systems. As these systems are supposed to be identical, and I'm getting inconsistent behavior, I'd like to track down what could possibly be different (in case there are other side effects I haven't noticed yet, and needs fixed).

Comment: Are you comparing the results for the same user?

Comment: @tomasz - Yes. Those results were all run as myself. I can try as another user, but hadn't thought to try since others reported the same behavior.

Comment: With these persmissions (`-rwxr-x---`) and `root:root` there's likely not much to relate to here. I feel this question is steering into an unclear direction.