# nslcd.conf permission problem

Tags: permissions

I have a fresh AlmaLinux 8.8 installation where I have installed the nss-pam-ldap package.

When I try to restart the nslcd service it fails:

```
# systemctl restart nslcd.service 
Job for nslcd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nslcd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Amongst other things, `journalctl -xe` gives:

```
Unit nslcd.service has begun starting up.
Nov 11 13:09:24 nslcd[99425]: nslcd: cannot open config file (/etc/nslcd.conf): Permission denied
Nov 11 13:09:24 systemd[1]: nslcd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 11 13:09:24 systemd[1]: nslcd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

My `nslcd.conf` reads:

```
# The user and group nslcd should run as.
uid root
gid root

uri ldaps://some.stuff.de
base ou=dir,dc=some,dc=stuff,dc=de

# SSL options
#ssl off
tls_reqcert demand
tls_cacertfile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Permissions:

```
# ls -l nslcd.conf 
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 684 Nov 11 13:07 nslcd.conf
```

I manually changed the permission of `/var/run/nslcd` from `nslcd:root` to `root:root`. I am out ideas what may cause the the process to read the conf file.

Comment: It looks like your conf file has a SELinux  security context set - see [What does a dot after the file permission bits mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102624/what-does-a-dot-after-the-file-permission-bits-mean)

Comment: Wow, thanks for noticing. I disabled selinux and removed the security context.

Comment: @SimonT. Um... Disabling SELinux is unlikely the correct solution. I'm not a Linux user, but I think it would be better to work with SELinux to correctly set the extended attributes on the file than to disable the protection system-wide.